# How do I make Facebook Login page redirect on same page instead of popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the following code to do Facebook login:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Face Book Login Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APPID',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<script>

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
});

{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
</script>

<fb:login-button 
  scope="public_profile,email"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<script>
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in a pop up window appearing when the log in button is clicked. How do I change it from a pop up to instead redirecting my page to Facebook.